# ReactJS no muestra los componentes por estar en StrictMode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, npm

Buen dia, estoy retomando mis proyectos de react y no visualizo el componete card, viendo el inspector veo que hay problemas con el strictmode (no utilice esa propiedad)

adjunto el link de github

https://github.com/gianfrancomalzone/ReactJSMalzone34765

[image: En la imagen remarco el error del inspector]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.